# Launch or focus an app with slate window manager?

Tags: macos

I recently started using the [slate window manager](https://github.com/jigish/slate) for Mac OS.  I had previously used triggers in [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com) to launch or give focus to particular apps.

That is, cmd+f2 would launch "Google Chrome" if it were not running or would just give focus to "Google Chrome" if it already were running.

Is there an easy/idiomatic way to achieve the same effect with Slate?

My `.slate.js` contains

```
"f2:cmd": S.op("focus", {"app": "Google Chrome"}),
"f4:cmd": S.op("focus", {"app": "Jump Desktop"}),
```

I could change that to something like this:

```
var runIfMap  = {
    "Jump Desktop": "/Applications/Jump Desktop.app",
    "Google Chrome": "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"
};

function runIf(name) {
    var running = false;
    slate.eachApp(function (app) {
        if (app.name() == name) {
            running = true;
        }
    });
    if (running) {
        slate.log(name + " is running");
    } else {
        slate.log(name + " is not running");
        if (runIfMap[name]) {
            var str = "/usr/bin/open \"" + runIfMap[name] + "\"";
            slate.log("running [" + str + "]");
            slate.shell(str);
        }
    }
}
```

⋮

```
"f2:cmd": function() {
    runIf("Google Chrome");
    S.op("focus", {"app": "Google Chrome"}).run();
},

"f4:cmd": function() {
    runIf("Jump Desktop");
    S.op("focus", {"app": "Jump Desktop"}).run();
},
```

but that seems like a lot of trouble.

Am I asking slate to do too much or am I just missing a more obvious way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, what the problem with your example is, but with this one Slate launches the Applications if they are not running. Maybe you have to state all arguments of the slate.shell method.

```js
slate.config("orderScreensLeftToRight", true);
 
// Create Operations
var pushRight2_3 = slate.operation("push", {
  "direction" : "right",
  "style" : "bar-resize:3*screenSizeX/5"
});
var pushLeft1_3 = slate.operation("push", {
  "direction" : "left",
  "style" : "bar-resize:2*screenSizeX/5"
});
 
var devLayout = slate.layout("devLayout", {
  "iTerm" : {
    "operations" : [pushLeft1_3],
    "repeat" : true
  },
  "Sublime Text" : {
    "operations" :[pushRight2_3],
    "repeat" : true
  }
});
 
slate.bind("1:cmd;ctrl", function() { setDev(); });

slate.default(["1440*900"], devLayout);
 
var runIfMap  = {
    "iTerm": "/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/iterm2/2.0/iTerm.app",
    "Sublime Text": "/Applications/Sublime Text.app"
};
 
function runIf(name) {
    var running = false;
    slate.eachApp(function (app) {
        if (app.name() == name) {
            running = true;
        }
    });
    if (!running) {
      slate.shell("/usr/bin/open " + '"' + runIfMap[name] + '"', true, "~/");
    }
}
 
function setDev() {
  runIf("iTerm");
  runIf("Sublime Text");
  var op = slate.operation("layout", { "name" : devLayout });
  op.run();
}
```

The focus should be on the application that was launched last.